# Problema con el cálculo de promedios

Tags: java, validación, excepciones

estoy realizando un ejercicio usando excepciones y validación de campos, el ejercicio consiste en ingresar tres calificaciones y devolver el promedio, el problema se presenta cuando se introducen letras en esas variables, al realizar el calculo del promedio las variables tienen almacenado el valor de cero aún cuando en la validación de datos se han introducido correctamente, muestro el código a continuación.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Principal{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        float calificacion1 =ValidarFlotante(Leer,"Ingrese la calificacion 1 (0-100): ");
        float calificacion2=ValidarFlotante(Leer,"Ingrese la calificacion 2 (0-100):");
        float calificacion3=ValidarFlotante(Leer,"Ingrese la calificacion 3 (0-100):");
        float promedio = (calificacion1 + calificacion2 + calificacion3)/3;
    
        System.out.println("El promedio es :" + promedio);
        System.out.println("Programa terminado");
        }
    //Método para evaluar la entradas de datos en las variables calificacion1, calificacion2, calificacion3
    private static float ValidarFlotante(Scanner Leer,String dato) {
        float valor=0;
        try {           
                System.out.println(dato);
                valor = ValidarFlotante(Leer);                  
        }catch(Exception  exception) {
                System.err.println(exception.getMessage()); 
                ValidarFlotante(Leer,dato);
        }
        return valor;           
    }

    private static float ValidarFlotante(Scanner Leer)  throws  IllegalArgumentException {      
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)$");
        String valor= Leer.next();
        Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(valor);
        
        if(!mat.matches()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El valor ingresado no es numérico.");               
        }
        if (Float.parseFloat(valor)>10) {
            System.out.println("No está en el rango");
            return Float.parseFloat(valor);
        }
        if(Float.parseFloat(valor)<0) {
            System.out.println("No está en el rango");
        }
        return Float.parseFloat(valor);
    }
    
}
```

[image: Imagen de la presencia del error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código lo tienes **CASI** bien. Te faltó un pequeño detalle, aquí te lo dejo corregido y en los comentarios puedes ver la explicación!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ValidarFlotanteRecursivo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Leer = new Scanner(System.in);

        float calificacion1 =ValidarFlotante(Leer,"Ingrese la calificacion 1 (0-100): ");
        float calificacion2=ValidarFlotante(Leer,"Ingrese la calificacion 2 (0-100):");
        float calificacion3=ValidarFlotante(Leer,"Ingrese la calificacion 3 (0-100):");
        float promedio = (calificacion1 + calificacion2 + calificacion3)/3;

        System.out.println("El promedio es :" + promedio);
        System.out.println("Programa terminado");
    }

    private static float ValidarFlotante(Scanner Leer,String dato) {
        float valor=0;
        try {
            System.out.println(dato);
            valor = ValidarFlotante(Leer);
        }catch(Exception  exception) {
            System.err.println(exception.getMessage());
            // En caso de excepción entras aquí y vuelves a lanzar el método... pero y qué haces con el nuevo resultado?
            // Absolutamente nada! Puesto que tras hacer esta llamada, el código seguirá ejecutándose y saldrá por el
            // return de más abajo, dándonos el valor definido al entrar: 0!
            // ValidarFlotante(Leer,dato);

            // Solución?? En caso de error, volvemos a llamar a ValidarFlotante... pero asegurándonos de que
            // devolvemos su valor, y no el 0 de antes!!
            valor = ValidarFlotante(Leer, dato);
        }
        return valor;
    }

    private static float ValidarFlotante(Scanner Leer)  throws  IllegalArgumentException {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)$");
        String valor= Leer.next();
        Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(valor);

        if(!mat.matches()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El valor ingresado no es numérico.");
        }
        // Si intentas validar que no sea mayor a 10 (imagino que era 100), o menor que 0, pero devuelves el número
        // realmente no estás validando nada!
//        if (Float.parseFloat(valor)>10) {
//            System.out.println("No está en el rango");
//            return Float.parseFloat(valor);
//        }
//        if(Float.parseFloat(valor)<0) {
//            System.out.println("No está en el rango");
//        }
        // Así que he modificado un poco el código para que no lo permita igual que haces en el anterior if!
        // Podrías usar un if normal, la diferencia con los else if es que si ha evaluado uno como true, ya no
        // evaluará los demás, con lo cual si tienes varios encadenados, solo entrará por el primero que sea true.
        // Además, como estamos comparando valores float, he añadido la "f" al final del número para indicar que es
        // un número flotante. No es necesario en este caso puesto que java hará la conversión por tí, pero es
        // una buena costumbre
        else if (Float.parseFloat(valor) > 10f || Float.parseFloat(valor) < 0f) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No está en el rango.");
        }
        return Float.parseFloat(valor);
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu análisis, estoy iniciando en Java y ahora con el tema de Excepciones, este es un fragmento del código que me han dejado por realizar y ya tenía horas sin avanzar, nuevamente gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Siempre es un placer ayudar a quien tiene interés por aprender! Sigue así y mucho ánimo :)

Comment: Solamente un comentario, es de gran ayuda evitar los "números mágicos", en vez de poner tu condición evaluando `> 10f` o `< 0f`, sería bueno declarar un `final float max` y un `final float min`. Esto para buenas prácticas y mejor lectura del código

Comment: Efectivamente, @EduardoJiménez, lo *correcto* es usar constantes. Pero como no estoy seguro de qué nivel tiene ya que está aprendiendo, prefiero no usar cosas que puede que no hayan visto en clase. Y como no está usando ni instancias ni variables de clase, pues preferí dejar esa parte como estaba :) Pero efectivamente, el uso de constantes mejora mucho la legibilidad del código, y hace que sea más mantenible!